# how to get a file from this PK fpþJ÷)file.txtKËÌI5äPK fpþJ÷)file.txtPK6 in python?

Tags: python

Below is my code:

```
response='PK fpþJ÷)file.txtKËÌI5äPK fpþJ÷)file.txtPK6'

with open('filecompressed.zip', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

but I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: `shutil.copyfileobj()` takes two file-like objects. You are giving it a string and a file object. What are you trying to do?

Comment: 'PK fpþJ÷)file.txtKËÌI5äPK fpþJ÷)file.txtPK6' represents a zip file ,so i want to get the real zip file in nodejs is fs.writeFileSync('file_compressed.zip', response, 'binary'), but I dont know how in python is

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `response` holds the actual file data, you just want to `write` to `out_file`:

```
with open('filecompressed.zip', 'wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(response)
```

However, that doesn't create a valid zip file on my system:

```
$ file filecompressed.zip 
filecompressed.zip: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators
$ unzip filecompressed.zip 
Archive:  filecompressed.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of filecompressed.zip or
        filecompressed.zip.zip, and cannot find filecompressed.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: response is not a txt file ,is a zip file,so I want to get the real zip file in my pc,response comes from a server